# Dúvida ao pegar grupo de checkbox repetido

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Estou fazendo um formulário de cadastro onde eu tenho todos os dias da semana para selecionar

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Segunda"> Seg
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Terça"> Ter
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Quarta"> Qua
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Quinta"> Qui
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Sexta"> Sex
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Sábado"> Sáb
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Domingo"> Dom
```

O Problema é que no formulário tem um botão **Adicionar +1** onde duplica esse grupo de checkbox. Como são checkbox eu coloquei o `name` dele como `array` e caso tenha mais de um grupo de checkbox eu não sei como fazer para pegar, pois preciso pegar grupo por grupo, ou seja, se eu tenho um grupo só irei fazer um `foreach()` com PHP e resolvo o caso, pois os indices seram de 0 a 6 (pois são 7 dias). Agora se tem 2 grupos, os indices seram de 0 a 13 e a cada 7 é um grupo e eu preciso dividir esses grupos.

Answer (score 1):

Tem que fazer o input como array multidimensional: `name="dias[0][]"`:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[0][]" value="Segunda"> Seg
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[0][]" value="Terça"> Ter
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[0][]" value="Quarta"> Qua
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[0][]" value="Quinta"> Qui
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[0][]" value="Sexta"> Sex
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[0][]" value="Sábado"> Sáb
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[0][]" value="Domingo"> Dom
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[1][]" value="Segunda"> Seg
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[1][]" value="Terça"> Ter
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[1][]" value="Quarta"> Qua
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[1][]" value="Quinta"> Qui
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[1][]" value="Sexta"> Sex
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[1][]" value="Sábado"> Sáb
    <input type="checkbox" name="dias[1][]" value="Domingo"> Dom
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if( !empty( $_POST['dias'] ) ) {
    foreach( $_POST['dias'] as $key => $value ) {
        echo "<br />Semana $key<br />";
        foreach( $value as $dias ) {
            echo "$dias<br />";
        }
    }
}
?>
```